# Sbt, compile compiler bridge

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to build a docker image with sbt.

Here is what i have:

```
FROM kondaurov/jdk-alpine:jdk8slim

ENV SBT_VERSION=1.2.1

RUN \
 echo "$SBT_VERSION" && \
 curl -fsL https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v${SBT_VERSION}/sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.tgz | tar xfz - -C /usr/local && \
 ln -s /usr/local/sbt/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ && \
 sbt sbtVersion

ENTRYPOINT sbt
```

When i use this image with my scala project i get this:

```
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings

[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources to /sbt_project/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...

[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.12' for Scala 2.12.6. Compiling...

[info]   Compilation completed in 53.746s.
```

As you see sbt always compiles compiler bridge for scala and it takes some time.. Is it possible to compile bridge in my image? I guess ***sbt sbtVersion*** isn't enough

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, i din't understand what you mean. It's not about symbols..
Sbt compiles compiler bridge for scala, i want to do this earlier

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, ok, thank you, output is fixed

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3469) could help.

Comment: How did you solve this problem: doing something like `sbt 'set scalaVersion := "2.12.14"' compile` in the image did not solve the problem at my end.

Answer (score 9):

It's triggered on the first compilation, so you can change the `sbt sbtVersion` line to `sbt compile`. Most likely you will need to add a simple Scala source file in the working directory to trigger the compilation (and then clean up the produced output).

You can also set a specific Scala version without creating a `build.sbt`:

```
sbt 'set scalaVersion := "2.11.8"' compile
```

or even several:

```
sbt 'set crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.6")' '+compile'
```

Comment: An empty scala source file works (`touch a.scala`).